# Prove that every element of $S_{n}$ can be written as a product $\sigma$ $= \tau_{1} . \tau_{2} ... \tau_{r} $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that every element of $S_{n}$ can be written as a product $\sigma$ $= \tau_{1} . \tau_{2} ... \tau_{r} $ of  "flips"$  \\ (1,2)\ (2,3)\  ...\ (n-1,n) \ (n,1)$

of adjacent elements in the cyclically ordered set $[1,n]$.

Note: It also suffices to show that any 2-cylce $(i,j)$ is a product of "flips".

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show that the 2-cycle that interchanges $1$ and $3$ is a product of such "flips"?

Comment: You can do it by induction: once you have proved it for $S_n$, let $\sigma\in S_{n+1}$. Can you decompose it like something of the form $\sigma=\tau_1\cdots\tau_n\widetilde{\sigma}$ for $\widetilde{\sigma}\in S_n$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: if you mean do i know how to prove that $(1,a)$ can be written as a product of flips? then i don't and if you can help me to show that, that will work as well!

Comment: I mean very specifically, the $(1,3)$ one. You should be able to figure out how to do that one with a bit of experimentation. Then try to generalize the method you used.

Comment: yes i know how to "experiment" and get it but i can't seem to string together a rigorous proof.

Comment: Consider what happens if you look at $ghg^{-1}$ where $g$ and $h$ are both "flips".

Comment: can u say a little more about that? thanks!

Comment: A nice way might be to do as advised by Luiz and use induction. Then you have all the transpositions in $S_{n-1}$ along with $(n-1,n)$ and you need to show that you also have all other transpositions of the form $(a,n)$. You can get these by noting that you can get $(m-1,n)$ from $(m,n)$ by using something like what I mentioned before.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

For *any* cycle $\,(i_1\;\ldots i_r)\,$ , we have

$$(i_1\;\ldots i_r)=(i_2\;i_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(i_{r-1}\;i_{r-2})(i_r\;i_{r-1})$$

and now, for any transposition $\,(a\;b)\,\;,\;\;a<b\;$ , we have:

$$(a\;b)=(a\;\;a+1)(a+1\;\;a+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(b-1\;\;b)(b-2\;\;b-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(a+1\;\;a+2)(a\;\;a+1)$$